# Achieve a percentage overlap with Autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

Let Say View1 and View2 are two rectangles with the same size. With auto layout I can set View1.Center X = View2.Leading to make View1 and View2 overlap halfway in the X direction. Now I need this overlap to be a different percentage, let say overlap 1:3 or any other fraction. How can I achieve this with Autolayout constraints?

Comment: You could have a hidden view/layout guide with a width constraint with multiplier equal to your fraction, then align View 1's trailing to the hidden view's trailing and View 2's leading to the hidden view's leading.

Comment: @dan I tried your solution and it worked well. I really liked it. I think you should add it as an answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this by creating an invisible view which has a width with a proportion of the the width of view1. And then setting view2 to be just relative to the invisible view. This way by changing the proportion that I pick i can achieve any percentage I need including 1/2 or 1/3.

Answer (score 2):

It is not as straightforward as setting view2's leading to view1's center X but you can do that by tweaking the `constant` property of leading constraint at runtime, preferably at where exactly the `width` of view1 has been set.

First do `view2.leading == view1.trailing`:

```
leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
```

Then, depending on where you define views *(within a view or a view controller)*, you update the constant of the constraint in question right after all the views have been laid out:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  leadingConstraint.constant = -(view1.frame.width / 3.0)
}
```

[image]

You can download [the sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uqzj4lr5ei9ohb9/AADTK6Mrg_B1gubeVEPs8o5na?dl=0) I created for you and play around with it for a better understanding.